# How is one to control the tab order (key view loop) of a modal dialog? runModalForWindow: ignores nextKeyView

Tags: cocoa, tabs, modal-dialog

Unless I am completely confused, it seems that `runModalForWindow:` ignores the `nextKeyView` properties of fields in an NSPanel.

```
#define RUN_MODAL 1
#if RUN_MODAL
    [ NSApp runModalForWindow: self.view.window ] ;
#else
    [ self.view.window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil ] ;
#endif
```

I've tried it both ways, and I definitely get the correct tab order when using the normal `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` and don't when using `runModalForWindow:`.
Am I missing something?  Or does someone know how to make it work when running modal?

Per a suggestion, I tried the following and got the same result:

```
#define RUN_MODAL 1
#if RUN_MODAL
#define USE_BEGINSHEET 1
#if USE_BEGINSHEET
    [ NSApp beginSheet: self.view.window
        modalForWindow: nil
         modalDelegate: nil
        didEndSelector: NULL
           contextInfo: NULL ];
#else
    [ NSApp runModalForWindow: self.view.window ] ;
#endif
#else
    [ self.view.window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil ] ;
#endif
```

Note that the "doc window" is `nil` because this is a mostly-background-no-UI app that just sometimes pops up a login dialog.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use -beginSheet:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo: ?

Comment: well the first responder may be different in each case, that (i would imagine) gets to dictate the tab order with nextTabView

Comment: Each interactive item in the dialog has a nextTabView link.  It happens that running in both modal and non-modal the same item is the first responder.  But tabbing in the modal version ignores the nextTabView link and just goes left-to-right-within-top-to-bottom, which is what I think Apple calls the "geometric" order.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was the Auto Recalculates View Loop checkbox in the Window section of the Attributes Inspector in the Interface Builder. It defaults to checked, but in a modal dialog if any of the fields are dynamically enabled/disabled (by, say, bindings) the recalculation punts to the "geometric" (left-to-right, top-to-bottom) order.

I believe that programmatically that corresponds to the `autorecalculatesKeyViewLoop` property of the NSWindow (in my case, an NSPanel).

Comment: And a camelCase grump: in what world is "autorecalculates" one word?

Comment: In the same world that Keyviewloop is a word, which is why autorecalculatesKeyViewLoop is a weird hybrid.